# How to change Search Bar 'x'(close) button to text 'Cancel' in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, searchbar, custom-renderer

I am relatively new to Xamarin forms, so please endure this with me.
I am using Search Bar Xamarin forms in Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
However, they look quite different on both platforms, i.e., Android and iOS. My project requirement is to make it consistent amongst all platforms.

My primary concern is to change the 'x' button on Search Bar in Android to text('Cancel') for consistency.
I purposefully want to change 'x' to text('Cancel') and not the other way round for project requirements purpose. Please find attached image for reference.

I have looked for answers on Google/Stackoverflow, but couldn't succeed with the answers since they had custom renderer for image replacement. My requirement being image to text replacement, I am not sure how custom renderer could help me in that regards.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the code ? C# and xaml

Comment: *"I am not sure how custom renderer could help me in that regards"* A custom renderer allows you to modify how a xamarin control is implemented on a platform (Android). TBD whether the change you want can be made to the Android implementation. If you add your code to question, then perhaps someone can figure out what to do. NOTE: No image is attached to your question.

Comment: the good way is to create a control - create a control view - add a entry and a button in a grid - create bindable properties and use it wherever it is needed